# Getting a zombie process after a ptrace signal sent

Tags: c, linux, signals, ptrace, zombie-process

I am testing ptrace and signals.

The problem is that when I am forwarding a signal with sigaction and then senting the interrupt signal to the process via `kill(pid, SIGKILL)` and after the   `ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, NULL, tracee_signal)` the process is printed as zombie at the output of `ps aux`.

Only when I quit the "master" process, then the zombie process has its return status collected by wait (at the end of the "master" process") so it stops being a zombie.

When I receive a signal the signal handler is called and the value of the signal is assigned to a global variable declared as `volatile sig_atomic_t gotsig` (Rockkind).

So at the main loop of the tracer I check that global variable for a value `>0` and then I `kill(pid, gotsig);`.

After that there is this `ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, NULL, tracee_signal)`.

And then the process becomes zombie.

Why does that happen? Is that proper behaviour?

**Addition:**
Could it be because we have to explicitly wait the child after the latest ptrace call? So as to reap its exit status?

Answer (score 0):

Referring your addition: Yes

As long as a parent did not process the `SIGCHLD` sent because of a child's death, the child stays a zombie.

In case the parent dies while the child is a zombie, the child is inherited by `init` (typically pid `1`) and under normal circumstances `init` does prcosess the pending `SIGCHLD`, which in turn leads to the child dieing properly.